# How I design a database to manage an article with complex content

Tags: mysql, database

I need to design a simple database to manage the events and news of a website, but the thing is in the content of these events and news sometimes require other elements in the content such as photos or tables of data.

So assume that I have a table called 'article' (since news and events may be considered as articles) which already had familiar attributes related to their authors, date, etc., then when it comes to the 'content' attribute how should I manage to handle this attribute? (the letter of the content is no problem, but how about images, or any other non-letter elements) should I consider it only 'string' type only? Or should I need to create some other tables involving in managing such elements? I am so confused, please show me some suggestions for this problem, thank's so much!

Comment: the database field could just store the HTML which will be used to render the article. That could then contain links to images etc in the normal way. if the user adds images you'd have to upload them onto the server as well. A WYSIWYG editor such as CKEditor could be used to allow the user to create rich content which is then translated into HTML which you store in your database (and of course you later insert this HTML into your news page for display). Or you could use some established CMS software which handles all this kind of thing already.

Comment: great, thanks, I feel much more relief now, I'll try your ideas! And how can I upvote you man (I'm just newbie)?

Comment: it's just a comment at the moment. If you like I can write it as an answer, give me a moment. You can't upvote the answer yet (you need 15 reputation for that), but you can _accept_ it (you have to click on the tick symbol next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks.

Comment: I added the answer now :-)

Comment: so that was your answer? :))

Comment: Yes. You can see it below. What else were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The database field could just store the HTML which will be used to render the article. That could then contain links to images etc in the normal way. If the user adds images you'd have to upload them onto the server as well and store them in the right location so that the hyperlink / image tag works correctly.

A WYSIWYG editor such as CKEditor could be used to allow the user to create rich content which is then translated into HTML which you store in your database (and of course you later insert this HTML into your news page for display).

---

Or you could use some established CMS software which handles all this kind of thing already.